# Set default query in express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm building a small e commerce project, and I have a 'Products' page set up with pagination,
but I want any call to my `/products` route to default to `/products?page=1`

This is my routes files

```
// list of all products
router.get('/products',  productsController.products);
```

And this is my controller

```
// products page 
exports.products = async (req, res) => {

  const pagination = req.query.pagination ? parseInt(req.query.pagination) : 12;
  const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 1;
  const prod = await Product.find({})
    .skip((page - 1) * pagination)
    .limit(pagination);
  
  res.render("products", {
    productsList: prod,
  });
};
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You show some code that looks to me like it would provide a default for you.  Is there a problem with that?

Comment: it doesn't provide a default. my question: when my '/products' route gets hit, how can i make it so the query '?page=1' is attached in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to make it so that any route that starts with `/products` has a default query parameter such that if `page=xx` is not in the URL, then `req.query.page` will be set to 1, you can just make a middleware that does exactly that logic:

```
app.use("/products", (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.query.page) {
        req.query.page = 1;
    } else {
        // convert string to number
        req.query.page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10);
        // deal with possibly invalid data
        if (!Number.isInteger(req.query.page)) {
            req.query.page = 1;
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

Then, just place this middleware before the first route definition that uses `/products`.

---

If you literally want the URL itself (as displayed in the browser) to contain `page=1` in the query parameter even if it was not originally in the URL, then you would have to do a redirect:

```
app.use("/products", (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.query.page) {
        let redirectUrl = req.originalUrl;
        if (redirectUrl.includes("?")) {
           redirectUrl += "&page=1";
        } else {
           redirectUrl += "?page=1";
        }
        res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    } else {
        next()
    }
});
```